Trouble proving there is no function $f$ from $\omega$ such that $f(i+1) \in f(i)$ for all $i < \omega$ in ZF.
I want to prove, in the axiom system ZF, that there is no function with dom$(f) = \omega$ such that $f(i+1) \in f(i)$ for all $i < \omega$.
Roughly speaking, I am aware that this leads to an infinitely decreasing $\in$-chain and that this would somehow contradict the axiom of foundation. But I cannot pinpoint where the axiom fails because of this.
I know that for any $n$, $f(n) = \{ f(0), f(1), ..., f(n-1) \}$ such that I get the following: $f(n-1) \in f(n) \in f(n-1)$ which seams really contradictory but again, I cannot pinpoint why.

I don't think $f(n)={f(0),f(1),\dots,f(n-1)}$ is true in general.

After giving it some thought, I have figured it out myself. I apply the axiom of foundation to the Ran($f$) and see that there is no element of Ran($f$) disjoint from itself. Since some element of Ran($f$) is equal to some $f(n)$ and $f(n+1) \in f(n)$ but also $f(n+1) \in$ Ran$(f)$. So they are in fact not disjoint.
